# React form data un-clickable uneditable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My form data in react is not clickable and uneditable. The cursor don't even show up when I click the text form.

[image]

Can someone please kindly help me with this problem?

I doubt that the problem is because my hash router:

```
import { HashRouter as Router,Route,Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

        <Router>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/blog" component = {BlogScreen}/>
            <Route  path="/" component = {MainScreen} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </Router>
```

The button in my main router "/" is work, but all form data in my "/blog" is disable.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should post code, not images and should post a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is the node version you are using ?